# Calling a function via Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink() VBA causes procedure declaration error

Tags: excel, hyperlink, procedure, vba

I am creating a new worksheet via VB which also contains hyperlinks to an online tool. The tool is only accessible via SSO. Thus, I'm unable to open the link and download information (error message, already discussed in other threads). The tool will be used globally by many users.

I've tried to build a workaround by **calling a function, which opens a browser first and then follows the link** (so that no error is evoked in Excel itself). I used:

```
Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
```

However, the procedures does not run and the following compile error pops up:

> Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 I was able to add the following to the Worksheet and it works as expected:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```